# How do I see my uploaded files and folders on Azure Virtual Machine

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

I created a Linux VM on Azure. And uploaded some folders via FTP. The folders go under /home/username/.
And I try to browse the files with the DNSServerName/home/username(e.g: example.cloudapp.net/home/username . But It is failed to load the url.
My question is how to browse the files that I uploaded.

Any suggestion and correction will help me a lot. Thanks.

Comment: When you say browse you mean list files via FTP? You most likely need to setup your FTP server to support passive mode, specify a range of ports and then open up the necessary Azure endpoints for the VM for those ports.

Comment: Yes. I am expecting to see the list of files. What exactly I am trying to do is to run android sdk over the Azure VM. I am not familiar with network configuration but I will try to do as you suggest.